# Interception consult

Tags: sql

help in heidy how to do an interception between two queries[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjb40.png)

Comment: Are you asking about `INTERSECTION`?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't ask a question and doesn't make sense.